# How to Upload To YouTube v3 using Access Token?

Tags: oauth, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I've gone through OAuth on a web application and obtained the access token...

Now, I figure I should use that access token to upload a video, but the API v3 doesn't seem to let me use it. I'm looking at [YouTube Data API: .NET code samples](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/dotnet#upload_a_video). In particular, this line seems strange to me:

```
UserCredential credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(secrets,
                new[] { "YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeUpload" },
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None);
```

The third parameter `user`, I guess is the user name. I don't get that info from an OAuth2 response. I don't even know what is a YouTube user name - I only see display names when I look at people's YT profiles, and those display names are NOT unique. What is this third parameter?

The function name `AuthorizeAsync` implies that we have yet to obtain authorization - but then why go through OAuth in the first place? Having an access token to me means that the user already authorized our app to upload.

I also found this possibility of being able to pass the access token:

```
var token = new TokenResponse() 
            { 
                AccessToken = "xm239jjks9f98900....."
            };

            UserCredential credential = new UserCredential(new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(
                new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer 
                { 
                    ClientSecrets = secrets
                }
                ), "userId", token);

            //GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow
            YouTubeService youTubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer() 
            { 
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name
            });
```

Just by the name of "TokenResponse" seems like I shouldn't build it explicitly. Also, `GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer` has the parameter for userId, which gain, I don't know because that's not given to me by OAuth2.

The `BaseClientService.Initializer()` also has the `ApplicationName`, which is what? I don't think it's `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name` as I copied from somewhere.

I tried to run the code above and I'm getting the error "The access token has expired but we can't refresh it" - but the user has just logged in within the last few seconds, so that access token is new.

Sorry if I'm asking something obvious, but the official docs don't tell me anything and similar questions to what I'm asking here on SO remain unanswered. Please help!

---

UPDATE:

In my case, all of the code resides inside a custom-made Web API function, but I think it will work the same on any server-side page (.aspx.cs) or MVC controller.

I found out that we DO keep the literal string "user" no matter who might be logged into his/her Google account. I guess the internal workings of `UserCredential` or `GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker` know how to pull the right data, maybe from cookies (?), and the `UploadAsync` function will know to which account to upload the video to.

I also used the `GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker` instead of building the `UserCredential` and `Token` from scratch (which resulted in the "expired token" message).

Now, the thing that I luckily stumbled upon after desperately trying anything, is that I needed to set up an Installed Application (Native) of type Other, which is SEPARATE from the web application. That Installed Application will have its own set of client id and client secret. Using those credentials, the upload worked!

... But there are some things that are quite not right. The user will be asked to authenticate your client app again - but there will be a new tab open for that consent, and when you click Accept (or OK), you'll land an empty page that says something like "access code received". Your upload actually happened but this is a very dirty and unacceptable user experience issue.

I'm still not satisfied as what I think I did is hacky/wrong.

Comment: I did the same code to upload videos to my account.  And it also opens the browser to get my authorization for the application to interact with my account.  That makes sense to me - you don't want an application to access your account without your permission - correct?

Comment: Correct. There's a consent that the user will have to agree to get into your web app (client-side) in the first place (for managing YouTube account and Google+ data). But when they click on your Upload button for the first time, they're presented that "Offline access permission" window for the server-side app that will do the uploading - it's all good, but the wording "offline access" would probably scare most users.

Comment: The thing is, I can't use the purely client-side uploading because I'm not asking the user to grab a file off his/her machine to upload to YouTube. I'm letting them upload a file that has already been saved somewhere online that belongs to them.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/moving_to_oauth#offlinelong-lived-access-to-the-youtube-api

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this exact problem.  By examining the code, I discovered that you can  work around the problem by setting the Issued and ExpiresInSeconds properties on TokenResponse:

```
token.Issued = DateTime.Now;
token.ExpiresInSeconds = int.MaxValue;
```

It's a hack, but it works like a charm!  It seems like the authors of the .net client assumed that you'll always have a refresh token, as they make it difficult to use the access token alone.  The java and python libraries are much more intuitive in this regard.

It does not seem to matter what you pass for the user strings.